# Method Reference not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, methods, reference

I have these 2 methods in my `class MainFrame extends JFrame` class:

```
// METHOD 1
private void connectBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        controller.connectDatabase();
}

// METHOD 2
public void exitBtnActionPerformed(WindowEvent evt) {
    int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            "Are you sure you want to exit the program?", "Exit Program Message Box",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        controller.exitApplication();
    }   
}
```

How come this works to call METHOD 1:

```
JMenuItem mntmOpenDatabase = new JMenuItem("Open a Database");
mntmOpenDatabase.addActionListener(this::connectBtnActionPerformed);
```

... to replace this:

```
mntmConnectToDB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        connectBtnActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

But this (in `class MainFrame extends JFrame`'s initializer):

```
addWindowListener(this::exitBtnActionPerformed);
```

... to call METHOD 2, does not work for when I try to replace this:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        exitBtnActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

Instead it gives me this error:

```
- The method addWindowListener(WindowListener) in the type Window is not applicable for the arguments 
 (this::exitBtnActionPerformed)
- The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **functional** interface is an interface that has only **one** abstract method.

The method reference does not work for the 2nd method because [`WindowListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) is not a `functional interface`; unlike the `ActionListener` interface which has a single abstract method [`actionPerformed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)).

Comment: Actually that methods expects a WindowListener - but the underlying problem is the same.